# Must a social network be moderated?

Tags: online

Is it legal (from the point of view of European legislation) to create a social network without any moderation?

I am just starting the project and I honestly have else to do than sorting through hundreds of messages. Also, I don't have the financial resources to hire someone to do it.

Comment: Since you will be responsible for any illegal actions that could take place, it is in your best interest to monitor it.

Comment: Why would I be responsible? Couldn't I be a simple content hoster?

Comment: If you host an illegal content, like copyright material, who do you think the copyright holdler will demand compensation from first?

Comment: I don't know perhaps ask me for the IP of the person who posted it

Comment: But it is your system where this was allowed to happen (**negligence**), thus the need to monitor to insure that such things don't happen.

Comment: If you have sources to support this I'll take it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is your project. It is for you to invest the needed time to gain the needed knowledge to properly bring about your project in a mannor that will bring you more good than harm.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't the purpose of this site to ask questions when you are not competent yourself? Answering "find out for yourself" seems a bit strange to me.
If there is a problem with the way the question is asked, I will gladly edit it.

Comment: This is permissible under U.S. law, but I don't know if it is permissible under the law of the E.U. or any of its member states.

Comment: *Law Stack Exchange is for **educational purposes only** and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner.*

Comment: @ohwilleke That may be true, but that doesn't effect a possible liability for copyright infringements.

Comment: @Blincer Why would they go to the trouble? It's the choice between a long, tedious process to track down what may just be some kid or a company that presumably has something worth taking.

Comment: Your location matters here btw. Include it.

Answer (score 1):

**What do you mean by 'social network' and what do you mean by 'moderation'?**

If you want to process personal information of EU data subjects, you need either their (documented) permission or another legal basis. You must safeguard the data and provide a contact for complaints, information requests, and corrections, among other things.

*If what you plan to do is not a routine case (like a store holding customer data or a sports club with membership lists), talk to a qualified professional.*

EU law varies from state to state on some regulations of 'social networks.' The applicable law can vary by the size of the network. You might be required to provide a contact point for *complaints* (both on the web and in the real, physical world) and to respond to complains in short order. If that is 'moderation' by your definitions, then moderation will be required.

*If what you plan to do is not a routine case (like a personal blog with a comment function), talk to a qualified professional.*

My points are just the basics and not intended to replace professional legal advice, and the advice of a qualified data protection officer. (You might have to hire one of those for your company, depending on what you plan to do.)